# How to call onClick(View v) method explicitly in an Android? Is it possible?

Tags: android, onclick, android-activity, android-orientation

I want to call an `onClick(View v)` of other class from my activity's method `onCreate()`. Is it possible?

Because I have a Popupwindow in an onClick method of other class, so when an orientation changes, I want my landscape mode's popupwindow to be intact and appear at runtime. How can it be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the onClick() you want to call is for a View *x*, use either x.performClick() or x.callOnClick(). Check their javadoc in the Developers Guide for more details.

Notice that you have to have a handle to x. If your orientation changes, you should destroy the PopupWindow and re-display it, which should work.

Comment: x.performClick() is what I was looking for, woohoo. Thanks a millions :)

Comment: `performClick()` is the right one. I don't know why but `callOnClick()` does not work for me.