# Android: Call OnClick for Buttons in main from an other class

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

Lets say my main screen has a lot of Buttons.

I want to make a class in which all the Button listeners are inside and call the onClick from my main method each time I press a button.

```
public class Buttons extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

   Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


    int viewId = v.getId() ;

    if(viewId == R.id.button1){
           Intent ScrollViewTest = new Intent(this, ScrollViewTest.class);
           startActivity(ScrollViewTest);}
      if(viewId == R.id.button2){
           Intent ScrollViewTest = new Intent(this, CameraTest.class);
           startActivity(CameraTest);}      
    }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call the onClick method like:

```
Buttons allButtons = new Buttons();
allButtons.onClick(btn1);
```

or is my logic wrong ?

........................................

Already checked

[calling a method from an onClick listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493480/calling-a-method-from-an-onclick-listener)

[How to call onClick(View v) method explicitly in an Android? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547299/how-to-call-onclickview-v-method-explicitly-in-an-android-is-it-possible)

[Android onClick method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733858/android-onclick-method)

[Is there a method to set methods for multiple objects in one go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476075/is-there-a-method-to-set-methods-for-multiple-objects-in-one-go/19476201#19476201)

Comment: Is it necessary that you pass a particular button in this manner, or are you just trying to handle `onClick` methods for multiple buttons?

Comment: No it's not necessary.
I am trying to handle multiple buttons in one separate class to keep it organized...

Comment: What do you mean by one separate? - Don't implement `onClickListener`, create a new `onClickListener` for each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Buttons extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);  // did you mean R.id.button2?

   // Create the onClickListener for btn1
   btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent ScrollViewTest = new Intent(this, ScrollViewTest.class);
           startActivity(ScrollViewTest);
       }
   });

   // Create the onClickListener for btn2
   btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent ScrollViewTest = new Intent(this, CameraTest.class);
           startActivity(CameraTest);
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to call the Button class from my Main Activity otherwise they don't respond.
There is no setContentView(R.layout.main); in this class so no Buttons here. Just a method I want to call each time they are pressed. Hard to explain.
Anyway I think Java doesn't work as I think. Have to study more.

Comment: If you explain it in a little more detail, I may be able to help you.  Why are you trying to do things with buttons in an activity that doesn't have buttons in the view?

Comment: Well You are right about that. What I should write is:
public class Buttons extends mainScreen implements OnClickListener{...

So I have the Button class that contains all my Buttons. Now I want to call it from the "public class mainScreen extends Activity"

Hope I got a little bit more clear.